# Resolving optional one-to-one relationship for use with SwiftUI ForEach?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two CoreData entities A and B, there is a one to one relationship between them. B entity records must always exist. Also A must have a relationship to B.

However, CoreData enforces optional relationship.

```
ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
  MyView(aItem: item, bItem: item.B)
}
```

Therefore, `item.B` above is an optional.
I need the `bItem` value to be an ObservedObject, however they can not be optionals

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var aItem: A
    @ObservedObject var bItem: B
```

I've tried wrapping an `if let` around MyView, but this cause a NavigationLink pop issue.

Which ever way I turn I face problems with the optional.

Comment: One way is to set code generation (codegen) in your model to manual and edit the files so you have a non-optional relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would deal with it here

```
MyView(aItem: item, bItem: item.B ?? BManager.create(itemA: item))
```

`BManager` being a Manager object that would hold a convenience method to create a blank object.

That way if `B` happens to be `nil` an object would get created immediately.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776338/unable-to-save-custom-data-into-coredata-using-combine-framework/69781410#69781410) is something similar it involves a `struct`<->CoreData relationship so it isn't exact but similar to this.