# SwiftUI: Trying to set my CoreData model for decoded JSON

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a small app that doesn't have persistence.  I have JSON file of 100+ countries as part of the app:

**Countries.json** (only included 1 for brevity)

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "display_name": "Algeria",
        "searchable_names": [
            "algeria"
        ],
        "image": "algeria",
        "latitude": 36.753889,
        "longitude": 3.058889,
        "favorite": false,
        "extended": false
    }
]
```

and my country model looks like this:

**Country.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Country: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    let display_name: String
    let searchable_names: [String]
    let image: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    var favorite: Bool
    var extended: Bool
}
```

and I'd decode the JSON like this:

```
 @State var countries: [Country] = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")
```

Now, I am wanting to add a way to persist data so that if a user togglers `favorite`, that country will stay marked as a favorite on subsequent app visits.
I am having trouble in how to translate this over to use `CoreData`.  I tried making a CoreData model called `Country` and added each property in but I feel like that is not correct.  I basically need a way to add this decoded JSON to CoreData so that I could manipulate a single countries `favorite` value.  I am bit lost at this point in how to accomplish this with a CoreData model.

Comment: "I tried making a CoreData model called Country and added each property in but I feel like that is not correct" -- why do you feel that it isn't correct?

Comment: @jnpdx maybe I worded that incorrectly.  What I mean is that I feel like I'm missing a major step of getting that decoded JSON into CoreData

Comment: You will have to parse the JSON and then create a CoreData entity of each item and save it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to save custom data into CoreData using Combine framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776338/unable-to-save-custom-data-into-coredata-using-combine-framework)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift/69335920#69335920

Comment: can you show the code you have tried already, and what is not working?

Comment: Core Data is overkill for this