# Passing data to subview with Core Data and MVVM

Tags: ios, swiftui, mvvm, core-data

I am using SwiftUI and Core Data with MVVM.

I have a ForEach loop and I want to pass the data to the subview. First I did this using a property like this:

```
@StateObject var viewModel = ListViewModel()

ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
    NavigationLink {
        ItemDetailView() // empty view
    } label: {
        ItemListRowView(name: item.name!)
    }
}
```

Then in the subview ListRowView would be something like:

```
let name: String

Text("\(name)")
```

And the view model where the ForEach is grabbing its data:

```
@Published var items: [ItemEntity] = []

@Published var name: String = ""

func getItems() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<ItemEntity>(entityName: "ItemEntity")
    
    do {
        items = try dataManager.context.fetch(request)
    } catch let error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

That works as expected but now I want to edit the data and pass more properties to the subviews. I think this means I need to use bindings and @ObservedObject in the subviews.

What I see commonly done is one would make a custom Item data type conforming to Identifiable protocol, for example:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
}
```

And then they'd update their ForEach to use the Item type and do something like `let items: [Item] = []` but I've already got `let items: [ItemEntity] = []` with ItemEntity being the name of the Core Data Item entity.

What I suspect needs to happen is in my getItems method, items needs to be changed to use an Item data type. Is this correct? Or how should I go about this? I'm shiny new to Core Data and MVVM and any input will be super appreciated.

**Edit**: I've seen this done too but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for:

```
ForEach(viewModel.items.indicies) { index in
    SubView(viewModel.items[index])
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
 Also show the complete error message, if any, and on what line in your code.
 
 Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app
 [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)
 
 And make sure you have `var name: String` in your `struct Item`, not `let`.

Comment: I think what I need to be looking at is mapping the Core Data entity model to the custom Item data type. This question [Unable to save custom data into CoreData using Combine framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69776338/1573326) seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your first attempt is fine there is no need for all the rest. If there is an error we can help with that

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes:

1. `ForEach` is a `View`, not a loop, if you attempt to use it with indices it will crash when you access an array by index in its closure. In the case of value types you need to supply the `ForEach` with an `id` which needs to be a property of the data that is a unique identifier. Or the data can implement `Identifiable`. However, in the case of objects like in Core Data, it will automatically use the object's pointer as its `id`, which works because the managed object context ensures there is only one instance of an object that represents a record. So what this all means is you can use `ForEach` with the array of objects.
2. We don't need MVVM in SwiftUI because the `View` struct is already the view model and the property wrappers make it behave like a view model object. Using `@StateObject` to implement a view model will cause some major issues because state is designed to be a source of truth whereas a traditional view model object is not. `@StateObject` is designed for when you need a reference type in an `@State` source of truth, i.e. doing something async with a lifetime you want to associate with something on screen.

The property wrapper for Core Data is `@FetchRequest` or `@SectionedFetchRequest`. If you create an app project in Xcode with core data checked the template will demonstrate how to use it.

Comment: I like the idea of separating business and logic, whether it's MVC or MVVM I don't really care. When I first started playing with Core Data and using the Xcode template it got a bit unwieldy as the project grew and a lot of code repeating between views. One issue with @FetchRequest is that it only works in a view struct.

Comment: Logic can go in `NSManagedObject` subclasses or extensions generated by the model editor. It can also go in extensions on `NSManagedObjectContext`.